# how to append the value of a variable to output file using makefile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I am developing a C firmware for ARM with arm-none-eabi-gcc.
My makefile already generates a flashable .hex file;
I'd like to customize the .hex file adding useful info. Of course it won't be flashable anymore, but that file will be used with a firmware upload utility which will be able to interpret that.
If possible, I'd like to include some useful values of variables from the project.

i.e. in main.c:

```
unsigned int version_num = 12;
```

content of output.hex file:

```
version=12
:020000040000FA
:10500000C00E0020355100004F51000051510000EA
:105010000000000000000000000000000000000090
:1050200000000000000000000000000053510000DC
:105030000000000000000000555100005751000022
:105040005951000059510000215A000059510000E7
...
```

Comment: The only way to do it is to parse them out of your sources (using `grep`/`sed`/`awk` or whatever needed) and then append them to the output file (using `sed` as well as an option)

Comment: Before you can do something with Make, you must know how you would do it *without* Make.

Comment: Ok, I understand that I basically have to code/use some external tool to generate and append the strings I need, and then just call it at the end of the makefile.
I thought there were some other magic tricks with make.

Answer (score 0):

`makefile`:

```
output.hex: .hex
    sed -n 's/unsigned int version_num = \([0-9]*\);/version=\1/p' main.c|\
    cat - .hex >output.hex
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.